# Pass Variables to SilkTest Workbench stw.exe from Command Line

Tags: .net, batch-file, cmd, workbench, silktest

Variables are not recognized

I hava a Silk Test Workbench .Net Script called Dummy

```
Public Module Main
  Public Test As String = "test"
 
  Public Sub Main()
    msgBox(Test)
  End Sub
End Module
```

I want to run *stw.exe* using Command Line and override the variable *Test*:

`stw.exe -dsn silktest -username user -password password -script Dummy -variable "Test=hello world"`

Following the instruction from the [example for using stw.exe](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/silk-test/195/en/silktestworkbench-195-help-en/GUID-9936D9FE-02E5-4D35-97F3-2185F2208EB5.html).

But the cmd return an error that said the variables are not recognized

```
The following variables were not passed into 'Dummy' as they are not recognized:
->test
```

Any wrong from my code? Or is there any way to access the variables from .Net Script by command line?

Comment: Please include the information by editing your question. Links to external resources are liable to become invalid rendering your question unusable for future readers. Relevant code & sample test data should be inserted in plain text, obfuscating sensitive data if required.

Comment: @Magoo Already edited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different function prototype for the `Main()` function that takes the arguments as a dictionary, for example.

```
Public Module Main
  Public Test As String = "test"

  Public Sub Main(args as IDictionary(Of String, Object)
    Test = args("Test")

    msgBox(Test)
  End Sub
End Module
```

You also need to add the variable to the script properties, open the script and view the `Properties` window for the script.

Now right click on the `Input` node (under the `Parameters` node) and select `Add Input Parameter...`.  A dialog will appear where you can enter the name of the parameter, select the type of the parameter, and provide a default value.

Comment: The variable still not recognized

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to add the final step, I updated the answer.